# I want to open question 793805 to post an answer and then close it

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I wrote a very extensive answer using a computer program to verify the identity given above, which honestly might be useful for future visitors and contains some good content at least about the levi-civita tensor. I want to include that answer in the closed question. I don't really care about getting any reputation from it. I'll include the answer to this meta post.

The reason I didnt 'post this answer is because close to finishing it I stepped away from my computer to help with a small family thing and by the time I returned the question was already closed.

Linked question here: [Demonstration of equation involving Dirac gamma matrices](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/793805/)

Comment: With due respect, I don't see how you writing an program so solve a homework question warrants reopening the question.  Should we reopen homework questions every time one contributor can provide an answer (which would almost certainly be always).

Comment: I think someone can run into the answer, learn a little more about how to compute the levi civita tensor by hand, and possibly realize that they can easily then verify other identities through similar code experiments/modification

Comment: The issue is that if we reopened a question whenever somebody wanted to post an answer to it, that would be equivalent to not ever closing any questions at all.

Comment: I did ponder on this a little, the statement "it would be equivalent to not ever closing..." is simply not true.  It would be equivalent to not closing questions that people WANT TO post answers to. The only reason I posted here is because coincidentally I had an answer prepared. I doubt most people are willing to go out of their way to find closed questions that have received poor reception and START writing answers from scratch. I certainly am not going to do that. So closed still means closed. I think its reasonable to use the meta to ask for exceptions once in a while.

Comment: This particular instance i'm clearly not successful but like I would encourage people to once in a while post on the meta IF for some reason they actually did put effort into something that got closed (which I believe is extremely unlikely to happen even if this request of mine got approved).

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, questions are closed by vote.  It is considered that the community has voted to close a question.  With rare exceptions (due to a very high reputation level related to a specific tag or moderator action for moderator reasons), one person cannot close a question.

By logical extension, that decision should not be over-turned by one person who wants to ignore the community closing the question.

There is a well defined process for reopening a question, which requires more than one person to vote to reopen.  Then it's considered that the community has voted to over-turn the close vote.

Is any of this perfect ?  No, no system is perfect.

Would any other system be better ?  Probably not because every system of voting would be flawed in some way or seen as flawed by people who didn't agree with the vote.  A system which allowed one person to effectively ignore the close vote (by asking to reopen for them and then close again) would be farcical as we might as well not close questions at all in that case.

> The reason I didnt 'post this answer is because close to finishing it I stepped away from my computer to help with a small family thing and by the time I returned the question was already closed.

I have experienced similar things personally and I'm sure most frequent posters have as well.  That doesn't mean you should expect the community vote to be ignore for you (or me).  You have to respect the community decision, but you are free to vote to reopen and you can hope that others agree.

There are, by the way, [many math applications which can handle tensor mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_software).